# Setting up Timer in Swift

Tags: swift, selector, nstimer

I cannot get a timer to work in Swift please help. I get the error `extra 'selector' in call`.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
   1, 
   target: self, 
   selector: Selector ("result"), 
   userInfo: nil, 
   repeats: true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval    (
   1, 
    target: self, 
   selector: "result", 
   userInfo: nil, 
   repeats: true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One from a method I wrote:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
            let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }

        func updateTime() {

        }
```